# content layout navigation and linkable urls

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin7

My Vaadin application is using a custom side navigation drawer widget that routes button events to the Navigator.  These views are then displayed in a contentLayout area.  The contentLayout is so the page can re-use the toolbar at the top of the page and the nav drawer without reloading them.

[image]

The navigator updates the URL fragment, for example:

Main page = http://example.com/#home

Dashboard page = http://example.com/#home/dashboard

I'm now at the stage where I need to implement sub navigation within the contentLayout region.  So if the user clicks on a link within the dashboard, it can display the new view while adding the new URL fragment info:

Dashboard + News page = http://example.com/#home/dashboard/news

And also generate a permanent link for users to easily share or bookmark:

Dashboard + News page + News item = http://example.com/#home/dashboard/news/?item=123543432

I'm considering using a Subscribe/Publish pattern for the calls to navigate the contentLayout but I'm concerned with concurrent users and if the Publish events might get consumed by another user.  Is there a clearly defined guide in how to handle the separation of user sessions?  (Assuming to never use 'static' for example?)

Secondly, how would the application be able to handle a 'perma-link' like the News item example?  I've only seen Navigator used to reactively modify the URL from an event, can it proactively handle a request for a specific URL?  Or another component of Vaadin is meant to handle this?  Maybe tie it through a RequestListener?

My primary concern right now is the sub-navigation solution.  I don't want to have to inject the Navigator into every single view that might possibly need to open another view or close its view.

Comment: You can't pass a query string after the #! to the navigator. You can pass in arguments though. http://example.com/#home/dashboard/news/?item=123543432 could be http://example.com/#home/dashboard/news/item/123543432 and you would be able to extract the number in your view.

Answer (score 0):

When you don't wish to use the Navigator, you can handle the URL stuff yourself.

- You must then listen for URI Fragment changes.
- The "links" you have on the left side are not realy links, but buttons which have a onclick event registered, which then allows you to modify your page(s)

[Here](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/advanced/advanced-urifu.html) is the concerning documentation.

As for the user separation:

- It is done by default
- When you have some event bus/queue, then you will have to add a session ID if you wish to restrict the messages to one session